# Dataset for allocating the time of employees to the tasks

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, computing, large-datasets

I have written an algorithm for allocating the time of the company's employees to the tasks that need to be done by the company. Now, to evaluate the results of that algorithm, it is necessary to test it with a dataset in that field. Do you know such a dataset?
Do we have datasets with labels to divide members between tasks?
Do you know of another dataset that I can adapt it to the task allocation problem?